# D3, Flask, Pythonanywhere, problems with csv files

Tags: javascript, python, csv, d3.js

I am new to d3.js. I am trying to deploy this example on my Flask application. However, it constantly gives me an error- "data.cvs NOT FOUND". My Flask application files looks like this:`

```
├── flask_app.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── line_plot.css
│   │   ├── qtr_stats.csv
│   │   ├── table.css
│   │   └── thumbnail-gallery.css
│   ├── fonts
│   └── js
│       ├── d3.v2.min.js
│       ├── drawLinePlot.js
│       ├── jquery.js
│       ├── load_qtrly_stats.js
│       ├── makeMultiTable.js
│       ├── qtr_stats.csv
│       ├── setupPlot.js
│       └── toggleStat.js
├── templates
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── data_table.html
│   ├── drawLinePlot.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── qtr_stats.csv
```

How shoold look like my path to the csv files? `d3.csv("/static/qtr_stats.csv/", function(crd)`

Comment: You're showing the path structure quite clearly yourself -- `d3.csv("static/js/qtr_stats.csv", ...)` should work fine.

Comment: but it doesn't. The `d3.csv("/static/qtr_stats.csv/", function(crd)` statement is in load_qtrly_stats.js file.

Comment: The slash at the end of the path looks wrong -- shouldn't it be `d3.csv("/static/qtr_stats.csv", function(crd)` instead of `d3.csv("/static/qtr_stats.csv/", function(crd)`?

Comment: And you don't need the slash at the beginning either. Have you tried exactly the string that I've posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you told your server to serve static content from the `static` folder, then you don't need to provide the name of that folder in your url.

Your file should be accessible at the url `/js/qtr_stats.csv`, not `/static/js/qtr_stats.csv`

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with Overdrivr. In my case

```
// get the data
d3.csv("/static/js/data.csv", function(error, data) { ...
```

was the solution that worked.

I used Flask 0.12.2 and d3 v4